# Magnify.exe command line args

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, magnify

Does anyone know if there is any command line args that i could pass to the windows magnifier (magnify.exe) so it would open using the Lens view.

Or maybe some other way, I tried opening and sending a keyboard input using the shortcut to change the view, but often it blinks before changing the view! =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Magnify.exe /?` on the command line does not expose any sort of help for the executable.  And a search online does not seem to provide evidence of any command line arguments.  Leads me to conclude that magnify.exe does not take command line arguments.

I recommend reading this article on [sending keystrokes to another application.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C) His demo app worked for me to send keyboard shortcuts to magnify.exe.  His source code is available as well so you can integrate into your application.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the need to do the same thing, and wound up here trying to find a solution.  It's ridiculous to think that they wouldn't have a command line switch to set the views, so I started just trying some.   And behold!  I scored:

- **Magnify.exe /lens**   (defaults to lens view)
- **Magnify.exe /fullscreen** (defaults to fullscreen view)
- **Magnify.exe /docked** (defaults to docked view)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a great case for the UNIX "strings" utility, of which there is a Sysinternals version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings)

It takes some digging and testing, but I found these options:

- wait (doesn't magnify until you hit a key)
- noutilman
- hardwarebuttonlaunch
- fullscreen
- lens
- docked
- hilight
- globalhotkey

Answer (score 0):

you could try something with autoit, its a scripting language similar to basic that is really well suited for automating tasks

Answer (score 0):

Along those lines this autoit script might be helpful - it lists some msdn doco and if you know
autoit a script.

[Maginifier UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/161193-magnifier-functions-windows-vista-magnifier-manipulation/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a work-around.
I created a Windows-8-style batch file that has a command "magnify /on".
I'm not sure if the "/on" part is necessary.
The program that I am trying to magnify, 
(which is an old DOS program that runs in a DOS-Box),
launches with the magnify window conveniently available for me to change the magnification setting.
I tried to include a command after closing, "magnify /off", but it does not work;
therefore the magnifier window box has to be clicked to change the magnification back to normal.